# Best Method to Select Options in a HTML Multi-Select List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am looking for the best method, jQuery or pure JS to select options found in a Multi-Select List.

The basic Option List is this:

```
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option id="1" value="1">Multiple1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Multiple2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Multiple3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Multiple3</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Multiple3</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Multiple3</option>
</select>
```

I have an JS Array ['Multiple1','Multiple3']

I am trying to select the Array options found in the list automatically. So my list would then be:

```
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option id="1" value="1" selected>Multiple1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Multiple2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3" selected>Multiple3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Multiple3</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Multiple3</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Multiple3</option>
</select>
```

Please help.

Comment: Post your already tried code

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through your `option`s and check these which are presented in your array.

```js
var selected = ['Multiple1', 'Multiple3'];

$("#multiple > option").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    if ($.inArray(name, selected) !== -1)
       $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option id="1" value="1">Multiple1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Multiple2</option>
  <option id="3" value="3">Multiple3</option>
  <option id="4" value="4">Multiple3</option>
  <option id="5" value="5">Multiple3</option>
  <option id="6" value="6">Multiple3</option>
</select>
```

**Note 1:** You cannot use number as an HTML id. It is incorrect:

```
<option id="6" ...
```

**Note 2:** You use string content for searching. If you need to select **all** items with name 'Multiple3' then it is ok. Otherwise, it is better to use unique value like `value`:

```js
var selected = ["1", "3", "5", "6"];

$("#multiple > option").each(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if ($.inArray(val, selected) !== -1)
    $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
      <option id="1" value="1">Multiple1</option>
      <option id="2" value="2">Multiple2</option>
      <option id="3" value="3">Multiple3</option>
      <option id="4" value="4">Multiple3</option>
      <option id="5" value="5">Multiple3</option>
      <option id="6" value="6">Multiple3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

1206ms

```
$("#multiple > option").filter(function(id,item) {
 return $.inArray( $(this).text(), selected) !== -1}).prop('selected', true);
};
```

1610ms

```
$("#multiple > option").each(function() {
 var name = $(this).text();
 if ($.inArray(name, selected) !== -1)
    $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7coojoq9/2/)